# Is it possible to automatically invoke a function call during property access in Javascript/Coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

For example, here's my "Hello" machine:

```
hello_machine = new HelloMachine;
```

At this point, if someone tries to access a property in `hello_machine`, I'd like the following to happen.

```
hello_machine.fred;
hello_machine.greetings(); // output: Hi, fred!

hello_machine.george;
hello_machine.greetings(); // output: Hi, george!
```

I'd like this to happen automatically, regardless of the property they are trying to access. *I don't want anything hard-coded*.

This is the function that I would like called:

```
function set_buddy(name) {
  buddy = name;
}
```

And greetings would be the following:

```
function greetings() {
  alert('Hi, ' + buddy);
}
```

The obvious solution is to **not do this**. It's terrible practice and it changes a very fundamental way Javascript behaves. However, I'm in a position where this type of behavior would be fantastic to have.

My gut tells me that this isn't possible, and the internet has not been able to dissuade me of that fact (my head tells me I'm a fool for asking). But I know that Javascript is a fickle mistress and it would not surprise me if this functionality existed. Therefore, if anyone knows of any hack I can implement to get this behavior, I would surely appreciate it.

Comment: You want properties; setters and getters. The only way I know of to do this would be using proxies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, you cannot do this without proxies: http://soft.vub.ac.be/~tvcutsem/proxies/

Which aren't widely supported at all yet.  Not even close.

If the properties you wish to invoke were known before hand, you could declare getter methods with `Object.define_property` which is a bit more widely supported.  But without knowing the properties to be invoked ahead of time, there is no way to intercept them without proxies.

Comment: Thank you. I was very fearful that the above would be a stupid question, but I'm glad to see that I'm not the only lunatic that saw value in this. :)

Comment: However, I do feel compelled to add that quality JS code should never change any state from the accessing of a property.  It just feels wrong, and fails the principle of least surprise.  Getter methods should be used to return a calculated value, but not actually change any state.  If you want to run state changing code in a setter method `foo.bar = 123` that's fine because you are explicitly setting state.  I'm having a hard time believing anything good can come from your approach here.

Comment: I'm attempting to make a procedural templating language. I feel the approach makes sense in a *very* narrow scope. This would be one of them. For example, `my_object.table.tr.td.export()` would output `<table><tr><td>`.  Having them dynamic would allow me make it significantly more compact while maintaining a slick syntax structure. As it stands, I'll either have to do something like `my_object.tag('table').tag('tr').tag('td')` or hard-code in each function like `my_object.table().tr().td()`. I'm leaning toward the second for usability's sake. What's a few kilobytes anyway?